# Read xlsx from azure blob storage to pandas dataframe without creating temporary file

Tags: python, pandas, azure

I am trying to read a xlsx file from an Azure blob storage to a pandas dataframe without creating a temporary local file. I have seen many similar questions,
 e.g. [Issues Reading Azure Blob CSV Into Python Pandas DF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61935564/issues-reading-azure-blob-csv-into-python-pandas-df), but haven't managed to get the proposed solutions to work.

Below code snippet results in a `UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x87 in position 14: invalid start byte` exception.

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd
from azure.storage.blob import BlobClient, BlobServiceClient

blob_client = BlobClient.from_blob_url(blob_url = url + container + "/" + blobname, credential = token)   
blob = blob_client.download_blob().content_as_text()   
df = pd.read_excel(StringIO(blob))
```

Using a temporary file, I do manage to make it work with the following code snippet:

```
blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient(account_url = url, credential = token)
blob_client = blob_service_client.get_blob_client(container=container, blob=blobname)

with open(tmpfile, "wb") as my_blob:
    download_stream = blob_client.download_blob()
    my_blob.write(download_stream.readall())

data = pd.read_excel(tmpfile)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Similar to what you have already done, we could use [`download_blob()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-storage-blob/azure.storage.blob.blobclient?view=azure-python#download-blob-offset-none--length-none----kwargs-) to get the [`StorageStreamDownloader`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-storage-blob/azure.storage.blob.storagestreamdownloader?view=azure-python) object into memory, then [`context_as_text()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-storage-blob/azure.storage.blob.storagestreamdownloader?view=azure-python#content-as-text-max-concurrency-1--encoding--utf-8--) to decode the contents to a string.

Then we can read the the contents from the CSV `StringIO` buffer into a pandas Dataframe with [`pandas.read_csv()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html).

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd
from azure.storage.blob import BlobClient, BlobServiceClient
import os

connection_string = os.getenv('AZURE_STORAGE_CONNECTION_STRING')

blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(connection_string)

blob_client = blob_service_client.get_blob_client(container="blobs", blob="test.csv")

blob = blob_client.download_blob().content_as_text()

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(blob))
```

---

### Update

If we are working with XLSX files, use [`content_as_bytes()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-storage-blob/azure.storage.blob.storagestreamdownloader?view=azure-python#content-as-bytes-max-concurrency-1-) to return bytes instead of a string, and convert to a pandas dataframe with [`pandas.read_excel()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html):

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd
from azure.storage.blob import BlobClient, BlobServiceClient
import os

connection_string = os.getenv('AZURE_STORAGE_CONNECTION_STRING')

blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(connection_string)

blob_client = blob_service_client.get_blob_client(container="blobs", blob="test.xlsx")

blob = blob_client.download_blob().content_as_bytes()

df = pd.read_excel(blob)
```

Since `content_as_text()` uses UTF-8 encoding by default, this is probably causing the `UnicodeDecodeError` when decoding bytes.

We could still use this with `pandas.read_excel()` if we set the encoding to `None`:

```
blob = blob_client.download_blob().content_as_text(encoding=None)

df = pd.read_excel(blob)
```